# How can I hot swap referenced DLL's without recompiling the Solution in VS2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, reference

Our solution has a reference to a DLL which is used to communicate to some hardware over Ethernet. We have created a 2nd DLL which can be used to simulate the hardware, so that our developers do not need said hardware at each of their desks.

The software should not know if it is using real hardware or the simulator. How can we swap the references without needing to recompile the solution?

Can we just name both references the same and simply register/unregister the correct DLL that we want to reference?

**[Update]** Note: The first DLL is a 3rd party DLL that we do not have access too. The 2nd DLL was created by us in C++. Our application is written in C#.

Comment: Does DLL1 talk to DLL2? Or is DLL2 a replacement for DLL1?

Comment: @Craig DLL2 replaces DLL1 entirely. It simulates it.

Answer (score 2):

Make both DLL's implement a common interface (ICommunicateToYourHardware) and code the application to discover the DLL via reflection rather than by reference.

**Per Request adding sample**

The interface in this example is called IAuthenticate, but you can use any interface in it's place. In this case I am actually looking for *any number* of IAuthenticate classes. In your case if the different DLLs are placed in the same relative path the same compilation will pull in the different DLLs.

```
 // We need a container for the DLL files that we find and then a container for the instances of 
    // the plug ins created from the dlls. In this test we are only really looking for One such plug in
    // but I prefer to use collections for such things as it allows for a more scalable design. This technique
    // works for 1, 100, or more plugins and/or methods.
    private List<string> _DLLS;
    private List<iAuthenticate> _PlugIns;

    private int LoadPlugIns(string Path)
    {
        /// Within the designated Path (and in all subdirectories) locate all .dll files and put the path 
        /// to these files in a collection.
        GetDLLS(Path);
        foreach (string dirName in Directory.GetDirectories(Path))
        {
            LoadPlugIns(dirName);
        }

        // For each .dll file, inspect it (using reflection) to determine if it is of the iAuthenticate Type
        // if it is, create and instance of the object and store it in a collection, and assign a delegate to 
        // invoke its Authenticate method from the host application.
        foreach (string DLL in _DLLS)

        {
            Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(DLL);
            Type[] Types = myAssembly.GetTypes();
            foreach (Type myType in Types)
            {
                Type T = myType.GetInterface("iAuthenticate");
               if (T != null)
                {
                    if (_PlugIns == null) { _PlugIns = new List<iAuthenticate>(); }
                    _PlugIns.Add((iAuthenticate)myAssembly.CreateInstance(myType.FullName));
                }
            }
            foreach (iAuthenticate iAuth in _PlugIns)
            {
                this.Authorize += iAuth.Authenticate;
            }
        }
        return _PlugIns.Count;
   }

    private void GetDLLS(string Path)
    {
        if (_DLLS == null){_DLLS = new List<string>();}
        foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(Path, "*.dll")) 
        {
            _DLLS.Add(filename);
        }
    }
```

once we have the reference set via reflection we can invoke its methods like this:

```
    private void btnLogon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Authorize.Invoke(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtPath.Text))
            {
                this.BackgroundImage = TelefloraDemo.Properties.Resources._189469;
                this.pnlLogon.Visible = false;
                MessageBox.Show("You have Logged On!");
            }
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException aex)
        {
            DemoCode.LogException(aex);
            MessageBox.Show(aex.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DemoCode.LogException(ex);
            MessageBox.Show("No Authenticator");
        }

    }

    public delegate bool Authenticate(string Username,string Password,string Path);
    public event Authenticate Authorize;
```

Now, obviously your mileage may vary, but this should get you on a successful track. (Yes, there are other ways, I like this one..)

Comment: can you please elaborate. There is a common interface between both DLL's. Can you provide sample code for the reflection? Maybe an example?

Comment: Thanks @Cos for your helpful answer! Sorry, just to revise what I said, both DLL's implement the same methods (since the second one simulates the first). But, they do not use the same interface. The first DLL is a 3rd party DLL that we do not have access too. I have edited my original question to clarify this. Will your method still work?

Comment: @Ryan, then the method I offer can work for this situation. You will need to go ahead and create the interface that has the required method signatures, then create a wrapper class that implements that interface *and* calls your third party dll. Your mock class will then need to have that interface re-factored in. The central code base can use reflection, per my sample, to find and reference the target regardless of whether it is the mock or the production version, as long as the assembly with desired class is in the right path. It creates an layer of abstraction but it will work for you

Answer (score 2):

MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework) makes it really easy to do this sort of thing.  Just make sure your real and mock interfaces export the same contract and use MEF composition to have the desired version injected.

here is a [simple example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2008/09/29/simple-introduction-to-composite-applications-with-the-managed-extensions-framework.aspx) of how to use it.

Comment: Doesn't MEF require that the source is an SQL database? Can MEF be directed at piece of hardware with an API of some sort?

Comment: I don't quite understand that comment... MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework) lets you declare exports (e.g on c# classes) and imports (e.g. on properties) and compose your object based on the available exports that match your imports.  What those exports do (e.g. interfacing with hardware) isn't really its concern.

Comment: That explains my mistake, thank you. I thought you to be referring to Microsoft Entity Framework...

Comment: Thanks for the link. I read over the simple example, and it was very informative, however in our case we do not have access to the first DLL as it is a 3rd party DLL. As a result, I can't add `[Export]` attributes within it. Also, to make things more complex our 2nd DLL used for simulation that we created is written in C++. Will this method you proposed still work?

Comment: no, not directly. MEF only makes sense in the context of importing from managed assemblies you could write a thin interop layer that uses MEF, but there may be a better way. Are you P/invoking to the dll or doing something else?

Answer (score 0):

This is from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2%28VS.71%29.aspx)

> You can redirect an assembly binding
>   reference to another version of an
>   assembly by using entries in the
>   application or machine configuration
>   files. You can redirect references to
>   .NET Framework assemblies, third-party
>   assemblies, or assemblies of your own
>   application. Each version of the .NET
>   Framework has a machine configuration
>   file, and any redirection information
>   in that file affect all applications
>   running under that version of the .NET
>   Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Reference both and use a factory class to create the appropriate interfaces. You could then use some sort of external mechanism: config file, registry entry, machine name, build identifier, etc... to cause the factory to emit the correct interface.